# Overriding a pure virtual function with inline implementation

Tags: c++, inheritance, inline

I've come across a piece of code which boils down to this:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    inline void foo() { /* Implementation */}
};
```

I know the person who wrote this code is coming from a C background, so it may not be a correct practice. I understand that `Derived::foo` is implicitly virtual, but I'm a bit confused on whether the implementation of a pure virtual function can be inlined at all. Is this considered an ok practice? Does this inline function actually get placed in the vtable (although I imagine it would result in a compiler error otherwise)? Also, is inline keyword completely redundant, as definition in the class should imply inlining in the first place?

Comment: The definition is inside the class body, so even without `inline` keyword it will be "inlined" - meaning it will not violate ODR. As for a good practice, always safe to write `void foo() override {/* impl */ }` to get the compilation error in case of a typo in function name.

Comment: Two things. First, the `inline` is redundant; any member function that's defined inside the class definition is implicitly inlne. Second, the compiler will do what it needs to do to make that work. In some contexts it can expand the function inline; in others it can't. If it can't, it will create an out-of-line definition.

Comment: This is fine, but brings danger of duplicated RTTI if dynamic libraries are used and in some cases weird things may start happen.

Comment: I was just editing the question to take into account implicit inlining.


@MarekR can you elaborate?

Comment: I've seen bug once, when `std::exception` was derived as header only and excepting was not catch since it was thrown by other other library then catching place. Moving virtual destructor into `cpp` file binds RTTI to specific library and problem was resolved (I think I saw this as SO question).

Comment: @MarekR hmm... Okay this looks like more than reason enough to consider it a bad practice then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is already implicitly `inline` because it appears in the class definition.

`inline` is not what you think it is. It is not to control whether calls to the function are inlined by the compiler. The compiler will decide this independent of the attribute `inline`. It merely says: The definition can be in a header, no problem with multiple definitions will arise.

For example you could place all this in a header:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    void foo(); 
};

inline Derived::foo() { /* implementation */ }
```

When the member function definition is in the class body then it is implicitiy `inline`.